# os module is not working after flask project deployed on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, file-upload, operating-system

I have made a flask project in which I have used OS module to save uploaded files to a folder in my projects directory and do some stuff, its working fine in my pc but when I deploy it on heroku, the OS module is not saving files to the folder. please help me out, that  project is very important for me

Comment: Can you please [edit] with your code to show *how* you use the `os` module and what *exactly* is the error that you get. Also, you have a bigger problem: [Heroku's file system is ephemeral](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted). You cannot rely on storing uploaded files on your dyno's file system.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes at Linux servers `/child_directory` not works you need to specify all locations like `/user/home/directory`